# Adding /NODEFAULTLIB:library when building

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

Getting the following error when building:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: hw2_hci, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  Source.cpp
1>Source.cpp(373): warning C4551: function call missing argument list
1>Source.cpp(627): warning C4551: function call missing argument list
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__DescribePixelFormat@16
1>glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetPixelFormat@12
1>glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__SwapBuffers@4
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__CreateDCW@16
1>glfw3.lib(win32_gamma.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__CreateDCW@16
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__DeleteDC@4
1>glfw3.lib(win32_gamma.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__DeleteDC@4
1>glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetDeviceCaps@8
1>glfw3.lib(win32_gamma.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetDeviceGammaRamp@8
1>glfw3.lib(win32_gamma.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetDeviceGammaRamp@8
1>C:\Users\student\Documents\VSTest\hw2_hci\Release\hw2_hci.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Added the following, same error:
[image]

And this:

[image]

This problem occurs when I `Use MFC in a Static Library`. Why is this happening?

As someone suggested to go to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wtdswk0.aspx) page, I added the following as suggested without it working.

[image]

And the error:

[image]

After adding `gdi32.lib` i got the following error:

```
1>  Finished generating code
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll) : error LNK2005: _calloc already defined in LIBCMT.lib(calloc.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll) : error LNK2005: _free already defined in LIBCMT.lib(free.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll) : error LNK2005: _realloc already defined in LIBCMT.lib(realloc.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(MSVCR110.dll) : error LNK2005: __strdup already defined in LIBCMT.lib(strdup.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: __thiscall type_info::type_info(class type_info const &)" (??0type_info@@AAE@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMT.lib(typinfo.obj)
1>MSVCRT.lib(ti_inst.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: class type_info & __thiscall type_info::operator=(class type_info const &)" (??4type_info@@AAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) already defined in LIBCMT.lib(typinfo.obj)
1>C:\Users\student\Documents\VSTest\hw2_hci\Release\hw2_hci.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: You probably need to add user32.lib to the additional dependencies

Comment: @cup I added that, it resolved a few of the issues actually! However a few more remain!

Comment: Looks like you need gdi32.lib too.

Comment: @cup Again fixed some error, now it is displaying other errors!

Comment: Looks like you need to compile as /MD instead of /MT.  That is the cleanest solution.  You could /NODEFAUTLIB:MSVCRT.lib but that can cause problems like random unexplained crashes.  Basically if your program uses a DLL, use /MD.  Use /MT for standalone executables with no DLL dependencies.

Comment: @cup Did compile now, getting another error the classic `msvcr110.dll` when running on another computer

Comment: You need to install the VS2012 redist on the other computer.  Make sure that the redist is the same SP as the one you are using.

Comment: @cup I am suspecting that the trouble lies in one of the dll's I'm using, as it might be compiled in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that the default libraries specified by one or more objects (probably in a library you're using)  is asking to be linked with an runtime library that isn't the same as what your project is using.

The [docs on `LNK4098`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wtdswk0.aspx) are reasonably clear about what's going on and how to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: So your saying that `glfw3.lib` in this case is using `Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)`? As I have the project using `Multi-threaded (/MT)`? Is this where the issue is? (I apologize I am however new to Visual Studio C++)

Comment: Just so you know the suggested help did not help!

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the libraries to ignore in the 'additional options', add them under Linker/Input/ Ignore specific default libraries' (I see you already have glfw3.lib there, just add libcmt.lib separated by a semicolon).